# $\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} \cos(x) \exp(-\frac{x^2}{w})dx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\chi(x)= \cos(x) \exp(-\frac{x^2}{w})$

then

(i) $\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty}\chi (x)dx=0$

(ii)$\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty}|\chi (x)|^2dx<\infty$

my little idea is here:::

$\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty}\chi (x)dx=\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty}\cos(x) \exp(-\frac{x^2}{w})dx$

=$\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{2}(\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix)) \exp(-\frac{x^2}{w})dx$

=$\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{2}(\exp(ix-\frac{x^2}{w})+\exp(-ix-\frac{x^2}{w})) dx$

from here how to we solve thank you so much you all

Answer (score 1):

This is false. It is well known that $\int e^{itx}e^{-x^{2}/2}dx=\sqrt {2\pi}e^{-t^{2}/2}$. If you put $t=1$ and take the real part you see that that value of the integral in (i) is $\sqrt {2\pi}e^{-1/2}$ when $w=2$. Ref: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66677/characteristic-function-of-a-random-gaussian-variable

Comment: the function which i have mentioned is mother wavelet and it satisfies the about conditions

Comment: Maple agrees that $$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\!\cos \left( x \right) {{\rm e}^{-{ {{x
}^{2}}/{w}}}}\,{\rm d}x=\sqrt {w\pi}\,{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {w}{4}}}}$$provided $w>0$.